# LLVM 3.8: implementing a pass with ad IDE (Xcode)

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode7, llvm, llvm-clang

I'm a newbie in both LLVM developing and cpp.

I wanted to ask if there was a way to develop a pass for LLVM in Xcode having all the typical features available in an IDE like autocomplete and syntax code highlighting.

Right now I am just writing c++ code, checking everything I need on the documentation, but, as you can imagine, this is really slowing me down and it's really error prone...

Don't know if this can help, but my LLVM folder is structured this way:

- "llvm_3.8_source/"  root folder of llvm3.8 source files
- "llvm_3.8_source/build" root folder of my llvm3.8 build

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

LLVM uses CMake as a build-system generator. CMake supports such things as old good makefiles, ninja, xcode, and visual studio.

You can simply create Xcode-project using the following commands from terminal:

```
cd llvm_build
cmake -G Xcode path/to/llvm/sources
open LLVM.xcodeproj
```

First you will see lots of errors and 'red' marks. It's because some parts of LLVM sources are generated during compilation.
All files will be generated as soon as you attempt to build project first time and all the 'red' marks will gone.

You can read this article to get a bit more info on the topic:

[Getting started with LLVM/Clang on OS X](http://lowlevelbits.org/getting-started-with-llvm/clang-on-os-x/)

Comment: I am building llvm3.8 with the Xcode generator right now `cmake -G Xcode ..` from my **build_xcode** folder.
I'll and then use `xcodebuild -jobs=4` from my **build_xcode** folder.

Now what I'm asking myself is: how could I **implement a pass** that must be placed in **llvm3.8_source/lib/Transforms/<name_of_pass>** if my xcode project is   in **llvm3.8_source/build_xcode**

Comment: so I'm done and I can open the `LLVM.xcodeproj` with Xcode and it builds. After opening it with Xcode I have access to the source files of my **currently implemented passes** in `LLVM/Sources/loadablemodules/LLVM<Pass Name>/sourcefile/<Pass>.cpp`.
The problem is that now that I cannot add new passes without avoiding re-generating the whole xcode project again: in **build_xcode** folder `cmake -G ..` and then again `xcodebuild -jobs=4`.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately there is no another way. if you add new file, then you add to CMake as well, and then you have to regenerate the xcode project again.

Based on my little experience I can say that it's a bit annoying, but only first time when you're adding lots of files. 

Another workaround I used: created a few classes just in 1 or 2 files, and then split them into several separated classes at once.